# filling a char array with a string? c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to fill this array via user prompt. I was thinking to read in the user entry to a string and then assign that string to the array but that doesn't seem to be the right way to approach this. Could someone help me out?

The error I'm receiving reads "array type array[100] is not assignable"

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <string.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string theString;

        char array[100]; // ARRAY MAX SIZE

        int length = sizeof(array)-1;
        char * ptrHead = array;
        char *ptrTail = array + length - 1;


        //USER PROMPTS & ARRAY FILL
        cout << "Please enter a string to be reverse: " << endl;
        cin >> theString;
        array= theString;

        //WHILE LOOP SWAPPING CHARACTERS OF STRING
        while (ptrHead < ptrTail)
        {
            char temp = *ptrHead;
            *ptrHead = *ptrTail;
            *ptrTail = temp;

            ptrHead++;
            ptrTail--;
        }

        cout << array << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> array;` should put the input directly into the array, which I'm guessing is what you want

Also, there's a problem in your string reversal logic. You are reversing the entire array, not just the part that has been filled, which will put the filled portion at the end of the array. Consider using a function like `strlen()` to find out how long the actual input is.

Answer (score 1):

arrays are not assignable. You should use `strcpy` here:

But for this you'll have to convert `theString` to C like string.

```
strcpy(array,  theString.c_str() );
```

Then adjust your `ptrTail` pointer too , like following :

```
int length = theString.size();
char *ptrTail = array + length - 1;
```

[**`See Here`**](http://rextester.com/IHID8650)

Comment: It's compiling and running now, however it isn't reversing the string anymore.

Comment: @user7472073 See the link in my post

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks so much!

Comment: What was the problem that was happening when length and *ptrTail were being declared before the strcpy function? I'd like to understand my error better.

Comment: @user7472073 You assumed `length` will be always 100, which was not correct. It should be no. of characters in input.

Comment: @user7472073 -- If you just used `std::string` instead of a char array, and use the `size()` member function, then you wouldn't have made the mistake.  There really is no need to use char arrays at all, even if you state that you need to use pointers.  The usage of pointers is done to do the reversing, not the inputting of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the `string` to the array with `strcpy` or input the data directly to the array with `cin >> array`, but the better solution would be just not to use a `char` array, just use the `string` in your algorithm. That is also a better solution because you can overflow a fixed size `char` array

```
cout << "Please enter a string to be reverse: " << endl;
cin >> theString;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= theString.size() / 2; ++i)
    swap(theString[i], theString[theString.size() - 1 - i);

cout << theString<< endl;
```

**Edit**

The same using pointers:

```
std::cout << "Please enter a string to be reverse: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> theString;

char* i = &theString[0];
char* j = &theString[theString.size() - 1];
for (; i < j; ++i, --j)
    std::swap(*i, *j);

std::cout << theString << std::endl;
```

Comment: We were explicitly asked to user pointers. This is the route I would've gone if that wasn't a requirement. Thanks though!

Comment: @user7472073 -- You can still use pointers to do the reversing of the string.  The issue is that you used a char array to input the data.